# How to show the singularity is isolated when the following condition holds?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Definition: $f$ has an isolated singularity about $z=0$ if there exists a punctured disc about $z=0$ such that it is holomorphic in that punctured disc.

I read about the characterisation of a pole in terms of the following

> $f$ has a pole order $n$ about $z=0$ whenever there exists positive constants $C_1, C_2$ and $\delta>0$ such that $C_1|z|^{-n}<|f(z)|<C_2|z|^{-n}$ for all $z\in B(0, \delta)-\{0\}$.

Now, it is easy to see that $f$ has a singularity at $z=0$ but how can we see that this singularity is actually *isolated*?

I wanted to know the singularity is *isolated* because there was a lemma in my textbook saying

> Suppose $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z_0$ then $f$ has a pole there if and only if $f(z)\to\infty$ as $z\to z_0$.

Hence I wanted to relate two things together.

However, in order to show it is isolated, we need to show it is holomorphic on some punctured disc about $z=0$. How do we proceed with only knowing that it is bounded in the above fashion on $B(0, \delta)-\{0\}?$

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: In stating the inequalities it is **assumed** that $f(z)$ has a well define complex value in the punctured disk. There is nothing to prove.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you! However, for $z=0$ to be an isolated singularity, I think we also need $f(z)$ to be holomorphic in that punctured disc, not just well-defined. So I guess my question is how to show (or if we can show) $f$ is holomorphic in some punctured disk about  $z=0$.

Comment: You cannot prove such a thing. $\frac 1 {|z|^{n}}$ is an obvious counter-example.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ah I thought so. Maybe they have a different way of defining isolated singularity.

Comment: It's just that some things are not explicitly stated, rather implicitly assumed from the context. Here the implicit assumption is that $f$ be holomorphic except for isolated singularities in some neighbourhood of $0$.